# How to set default errorpage for httpErrors?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config

How to set default errorpage for httpErrors?

I want to specify default error page for all status codes

in the web.config

```
 <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <remove statusCode="500" />
  <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/CustomError/ServerError" />
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/CustomError/NotFound" />
</httpErrors>
```

I tried to set the 'defaultPath' in httperrors tag

```
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace" defaultPath="/CustomError/default">
```

but that is invalid :
[image]
[image]

any advise ??

thanks in advance

Edit:
Note, I am asking about httpErrors not about customErrors
the reason why I am using httperros, because I don't want to redirect, I want to stay under the same url.

Edit: Here is the error controller:

```
 public class CustomErrorController : DefaultBaseController
{
    public ViewResult ServerError()
    {
        var masterPageName = new SitePageBuilder(SiteId).GetMasterPageName("/");
        return this.View("ServerError", masterPageName);
    }

    public ViewResult NotFound()
    {
        var masterPageName = new SitePageBuilder(SiteId).GetMasterPageName("/");
        return this.View("NotFound", masterPageName);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have just modified my own web.config to include the following, and it works as expected. `<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
            <remove statusCode="500" />
            <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/500.html" />
        </httpErrors>`  Is "ServerError" a page or a controller method or something else?

Comment: ServerError is an action in CustomError controller

Comment: Please refer to the second linked question, "HttpError iis config throws exception when default path is added". As the answer there details, `defaultPath` is mutually exclusive with `path` on the individual error nodes.

Comment: <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/404.html" mode="On">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.html"/>
</customErrors>

Comment: The defaultPath attribute can only be applied if existingResponse="File".